# Declrative transaction management with spring boot and spring data JPA repository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I recently created spring boot REST application with spring data JPA repository.

I want  to define some rest services in read only mode and some other non read only.

Could you please help me how to implement this using `@Transactional` or AOP in declarative approach.

Also please share me any spring documentation where i can understand the transaction management using Spring boot application.

Comment: can you show your code first, please.

Comment: Did you try to google?

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of @Transactional in Spring is mainly for a reason of transactions, and do every Insert, Update, Delete, etc in the same transaction and if any of them would fail it would rollback the whole transaction and none of them will be executed.
You may se more information in [here](http://blog.jhades.org/how-does-spring-transactional-really-work/) jhades explains it perfectly well in his post on that blog and if you also need a complete documentation of the Transaction management you may see the Spring docs in [here](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html)